# unique message check in kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, logstash

We use Logstash and we want read one table from Oracle Database and send these messages (as shown below) to Kafka:

```
Topic1: message1: {"name":"name-1", "id":"fbd89256-12gh-10og-etdgn1234njF", "site":"site-1", "time":"2019-07-30"}
        message2: {"name":"name-2", "id":"fbd89256-12gh-10og-etdgn1234njG", "site":"site-1", "time":"2019-07-30"}
        message3: {"name":"name-3", "id":"fbd89256-12gh-10og-etdgn1234njS", "site":"site-1", "time":"2019-07-30"}
        message4: {"name":"name-4", "id":"fbd89256-12gh-10og-etdgn1234njF", "site":"site-1", "time":"2019-07-30"}
```

Please note that `message1` and `message4` are the duplicates with the `same ID number`.

Now, we want sure all messages are unique, so how can we filter `topic1` and unique all message then send to `topic2`?

The end result we want:

```
Topic2: message1: {"name":"name-1", "id":"fbd89256-12gh-10og-etdgn1234njF", "site":"site-1", "time":"2019-07-30"}
        message2: {"name":"name-2", "id":"fbd89256-12gh-10og-etdgn1234njG", "site":"site-1", "time":"2019-07-30"}
        message3: {"name":"name-3", "id":"fbd89256-12gh-10og-etdgn1234njS", "site":"site-1", "time":"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is known as *exactly-once processing*.

You might be interested in the first part of [Kafka FAQ](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/FAQ#FAQ-HowdoIgetexactly-oncemessagingfromKafka?) that describes some approaches on how to avoid duplication on data production (i.e. from the producer side):

> Exactly once semantics has two parts: avoiding duplication during data
>   production and avoiding duplicates during data consumption.
>
> **There are two approaches to getting exactly once semantics during data
>   production:**
>
> 1. Use a single-writer per partition and every time you get a network
>      error check the last message in that partition to see if your last
>      write succeeded
> 2. Include a primary key (UUID or something) in the
>      message and deduplicate on the consumer.
>
> If you do one of these things, the log that Kafka hosts will be
>   duplicate-free. However, reading without duplicates depends on some
>   co-operation from the consumer too. If the consumer is periodically
>   checkpointing its position then if it fails and restarts it will
>   restart from the checkpointed position. Thus if the data output and
>   the checkpoint are not written atomically it will be possible to get
>   duplicates here as well. This problem is particular to your storage
>   system. For example, if you are using a database you could commit
>   these together in a transaction. The HDFS loader Camus that LinkedIn
>   wrote does something like this for Hadoop loads. The other alternative
>   that doesn't require a transaction is to store the offset with the
>   data loaded and deduplicate using the topic/partition/offset
>   combination.
>
> I think there are two improvements that would make this a lot easier:
>
> 1. Producer idempotence could be done automatically and much more cheaply
>      by optionally integrating support for this on the server.
> 2. The existing
>      high-level consumer doesn't expose a lot of the more fine grained
>      control of offsets (e.g. to reset your position). We will be working
>      on that soon

---

Another option (which is not exactly what you are looking for), would be log compaction. Assuming that your duplicated messages have the same key, log compaction will eventually remove the duplicates when log compaction policy is effective.