# Handling possible duplicate messages when using AWS Kafka MSK with Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-msk

I'm building a Lambda function which will be triggered by a AWS Kafka stream.
I did some reading but could not find a clear answer whether its possible that duplicate messages will be consumed by the Lambda?

And if it's possible, is there a recommended way to avoid duplicate messages? either via Lambda logic or Kafka configuration ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57272421/unique-message-check-in-kafka-topic

Comment: Hey James, thanks. But as I don't control the Kafka side, then  it seems the solution is to store the message ids on the consumer side, and check for duplicates?

Comment: We duplicate check for example against a dynamodb table for this type of problem in some cases so I suspect the way you thinking is the right way if you cannot control the Kafka.

Answer (score 1):

The de-dupe needs be implemented in your Lambda function. You can store message ID in Dynamo to do it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).